# How do iterate through a number of rows and call vba depending on which line is flagged

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that retrieves a list of available reports to the user.  The user then enters an 'X' in a specific column next to the report they wish to generate.

How do I iterate through each available row and work out if the user has entered 'X'?

```
A          |         B          |       C          |  D
001        | REPORT A           |      fnReportA   |  X
002        | REPORT B           |      fnReportB   |  <NULL>
003        | REPORT C           |      fnReportC   |  <NULL>
```

OR

How do I iterate through each row when the list is retrieved and put a BUTTON at the end of each row that links to the vba to generate the report?

Comment: Use an Autofilter and then loop through the visible range? Try recording a macro to see the code and then amend it to suit your needs :) If you get stuck, simply post the code that you tried and we will take it form there...

Comment: Couldn't he attach the script to the page itself in the Developer tab so it's running in the background waiting for the cells in question to be used?

Comment: rather than putting a button next to each row, I would show this report-list as a liste in a dialog/form to the user. He then could use multiselect and a single button to create all reports. The other way, with iterating through your list, could also be solved by iterating through an array copy of your list, checking for col D and generating the reports if X is found, or generation reports for each row of an filtered list, as Rout said.

Comment: Why don't you just have him/her run the macros for each report directly? Why even bother looping through rows and generating buttons?

Comment: @Stepan1010 The XLS retrieves a list of valid reports depending on who they are, so I can't have a static list of reports.

Comment: OK. Seems a little roundabout - but I'm sure you have a reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`For Each` will do the type of search you are looking to do

A quick example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub testit()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("D2:D10").Cells
    If c.Value = "X" Then
        Debug.Print c.Row
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

This will print the row number of each cell that has an X.